# Prevent animals from making a den under a shed?

Tags: foundation, pest-control, shed, rodent

I am building a shed and like most sheds, the floor frame is on blocks, so there is a space of about 10-12 inches under the shed. I know from previous experience that foxes and rodents like to use such spaces. How do I keep animals out from under there? If you just put a skirt board down or something like that, then the animal just burrows under it.

Comment: mix broken glass into the dirt to discourage digging for cheap, then you can take up above-ground space with crumpled chicken or barb wire.

Comment: broken glass is just too cruel

Answer (score 5):

Some ideas:

- Lay heavy landscape fabric or galvanized hardware cloth and rock under the entire area.
- Leave the space open enough that it doesn't appeal to den-seekers.
- Install a skirt and place a row of pavers or large rocks around it.
- Install wire mesh down to the ground and then outward a foot or so. Cover it with skirting and landscaping.
- Install wire mesh to the ground and beyond, buried at least 12". cover with skirting.